# Finding the Height of a Binary Search Tree Recursively - how does it work?

Tags: recursion, tree, height, binary-search-tree

I have seen that a common solution to the problem of finding the height of a binary search tree looks something like this:

```
private int getHeight(Node<T> ptr, String typeOfCall)
{
    if (ptr == null)
        return -1;

    int leftHeight = -1;
    int rightHeight = -1;

    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println("Node value: " + ptr.el);

    if (ptr != null)
        leftHeight = getHeight(ptr.left, "leftHeight Call");
    if (ptr != null)
        rightHeight = getHeight(ptr.right, "rightHeight Call");

    if(leftHeight > rightHeight)
        return leftHeight + 1;
    else
        return rightHeight + 1;

}
```

As you will see, I have added some extra lines of code in order to try and understand how this method works...

Take the BST below for example:

```
                             99
                            /  \
                          50    100
                         /  \
                       49    55
                      /        \
                     48         60
                    /             \
                   47              70
                                     \ 
                                      80
```

The output I get with my added code is:

```
first
Node value: 99
leftHeight Call
Node value: 50
leftHeight Call
Node value: 49
leftHeight Call
Node value: 48
leftHeight Call
Node value: 47
rightHeight Call
Node value: 55
rightHeight Call  
Node value: 60
rightHeight Call
Node value: 70
rightHeight Call
Node value: 80
rightHeight Call
Node value: 100
height: 5
```

My question now being: How does the function know that it has to go from the leaf node with value 47 to the node with value 55 and then go down as far as possible from there? i.e. How does ptr.right.element = 55 when ptr is currently pointing at the leaf node with value 47? I thought that ptr.right would now equal null since it is at a leaf node? Also, once the leaf node with value 80 is encountered - the function goes to the right sub-tree. How does it know to do this?

Any explanation will be much appreciated! I feel that something about the recursion involved here is probably the cause for my confusion. How is this function able to work?
Thanks!

*EDIT* After Oli made the suggestion I added some print statements below the recursive function calls.

```
            private int getHeight(Node<T> ptr, String typeOfCall)
    if (ptr == null)
        return -1;

    int leftHeight = -1;
    int rightHeight = -1;

    System.out.println("Before: " + input);
    System.out.println("Before: " + ptr.el);

    if (ptr != null)
        leftHeight = getHeight(ptr.left, "leftHeight Call");
    if (ptr != null)
        rightHeight = getHeight(ptr.right, "rightHeight Call");

    System.out.println("After Recursive: " + input);
    System.out.println("After Recursive: " + ptr.el);

    if(leftHeight > rightHeight)
        return leftHeight + 1;
    else
        return rightHeight + 1;
            }
```

Output:

```
Before: first
Before: 99
Before: leftHeight Call
Before: 50
Before: leftHeight Call
Before: 49
Before: leftHeight Call
Before: 48
Before: leftHeight Call
Before: 47
After Recursive: leftHeight Call
After Recursive: 47
After Recursive: leftHeight Call
After Recursive: 48
After Recursive: leftHeight Call
After Recursive: 49
Before: rightHeight Call
Before: 55
Before: rightHeight Call
Before: 60
Before: rightHeight Call
Before: 70
Before: rightHeight Call
Before: 80  
After Recursive: rightHeight Call
After Recursive: 80
After Recursive: rightHeight Call
After Recursive: 70
After Recursive: rightHeight Call
After Recursive: 60
After Recursive: rightHeight Call
After Recursive: 55
After Recursive: leftHeight Call 
After Recursive: 50
Before: rightHeight Call
Before: 100
After Recursive: rightHeight Call
Below Recursive: 100
Below Recursive: first
Below Recursive: 99
```

This really helps to understand the unwinding of the recursion used here and how this function works as a whole.

Comment: You should add some further print statements **below** the recursive calls.  This should make it clear what's going on here.

Comment: Thank you Oli! Your suggestion has really helped me to understand the unwinding that takes place after these recursive calls - clearly showing how this function works! I have edited the code above to also have the print statements after the recursive calls.